# Django form picklist jquery sending list to django backend

Tags: jquery, django, forms, submission, picklist

**my usecase:**

On the frontend i have two div containers and each with a select multiple group.
The user can now shuffle items from the left "list" to the right.

Below that there are couple of django form fields that the user has to fill out.

After submission of the form i want to do something with the data on the backend, this includes all the items the user shuffled from the left "list" into the right "list"

**my problem/s:**

I fail to find a way to submit the **whole** right list  together with the form.

What i managed is to use jquery to shuffle items from the left list into a Django CharField (using a SelectMultiple Widget), BUT the data would only reach the backend if the user, not only shuffled the items into the right list, but also selected them.

```
test2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.SelectMultiple(), required=False)
```

What i want is a way to send all the items in the right list, to the Django Backend with the form submission.

**pick.html**

```
...
<div class="list-group">
    <select multiple="multiple" id="lstBox1" class="form-control">
        <option value="ajax" class="list-group-item">Ajax</option>
        <option value="jquery" class="list-group-item">jQuery</option>
        <option value="javascript" class="list-group-item">JavaScript</option>
        <option value="mootool" class="list-group-item">MooTools</option>
        <option value="prototype" class="list-group-item">Prototype</option>
        <option value="dojo" class="list-group-item">Dojo</option>
    </select>
</div>
...
```

Comment: What i currently do is on submit click, i use javascript to mark all items in the right list as selected.